# How to add a statistictical technique in caret model list in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to machine learn a statistical technique which isn't available currently in caret package. Is there any way that i can add this technique in library or tweak anything to machine learn an algorithm?

I basically want to machine learn instrumental variable regression. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely,

There are 2 ways:

1. You contribute to the [package](https://github.com/topepo/caret) repo in github or
2. Follow this [tutorial](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html)

Hope it helps